# Native Mac PHP IDE or Editor With Refactoring Features

Tags: php, ide, refactoring

I’m currently trialling PHPStorm and while I love the featureset and approach I cannot in my right mind fork over $99 for that kind of performance and UI. Does anyone know of, or even heard rumours of, a Cocoa IDE for PHP?

Until the time that something like that becomes available, the two features I really need the most are method and variable renaming and clicking on a method to be taken to its parent class. Is there any OS X tool that can do this?

I am currently using Sublime Text 3 and loving it. I had tried SublimeCodeIntel but it kind of sometimes worked sometimes didn't.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: I heard a rumor once...of an IDE that would write your code for you. It would even debug the mistakes it made and refactor as the code base grew. But it was only a rumor...